# Triple Databound Dropdownlist bound to gridview

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, data-binding

I have 3 databound dropdowns (Type) (State) and (City), I want the user to select criteria from the 3 dropdowns to display their selection in the gridview. All three dropdowns should be selected to display their selections.

How would I bind all three dropdowns to 1 gridview?

My database has three tables:

- `tblType` which includes student type
- `tblZip` includes City & State
- `tblName` stores student records

I can get the the City and State to bind to each other when customer selects State, city shows but the info does not display in gridview.

```
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ID],[City] FROM [tblZip] WHERE ([State] = ?)ORDER BY [City]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="State" Name="State" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="NID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource4">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NID" HeaderText="NID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="NID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceType" HeaderText="ServiceType" 
                SortExpression="ServiceType" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceStore" HeaderText="ServiceStore" 
                SortExpression="ServiceStore" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource4" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/rentalsold.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [NID], [ServiceType], [ServiceStore], [Address], [City], [State], [Description], [Phone], [Email] FROM [tblName] WHERE (([ServiceType] = ?) AND ([State] = ?) AND ([City] = ?))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboType" DefaultValue="NORMAL" 
                Name="ServiceType" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="State" DefaultValue="NORMAL" Name="State" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboCity" DefaultValue="NORMAL" Name="City" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Not related to C++ or classic ASP. Retagged.

Answer (score 0):

The way to generally solve this type of problem is to include validation code called whenever a new value is selected from the dropdowns.
In that code, you first make sure that all values are correct, then once they are, you bind the grid.
For instance, in pseudo-code:

```
TypeDropDown_AfterChangeEvent() {
   ValidateAndBind();
}

StateDropDown_AfterChangeEvent() {
   ValidateAndBind();
}

CityDropDown_AfterChangeEvent() {
   ValidateAndBind();
}

ValidateAndBind() {
    if (TypeDropDown != null && StateDropDown != null && CityDropDown != null) {
        BindDataSource(); // Whatever that is
    } else {
        UnBindDataSource();
    }
}
```